# cors issue when throwing a runtime exception with spring and docker

Tags: angular, spring, docker, cors, digital-ocean

I' building a web app using spring, angular and docker. I also have for the moment two environments. A dev environment where angular is served using `npm start` and spring using `mvn spring-boot:run`. And a test environment where I use digitalocean to host my app and containerize the angular and spring apps using docker.

In this application I have a registration page where user can register and a spring controller to handle registration request. Here is the code for my controller :

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public SaveUserDto register(@RequestBody @Valid SaveUserDto saveUserDto, WebRequest request) {

        User userToSave = this.modelMapper.map(saveUserDto, User.class);
        User registeredUser = null;
        try {
            registeredUser = this.registrationService.register(userToSave);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e.getRootCause().toString().contains("uk_pfki8mu6sefesty9h30d4n3yv")) {
                throw new EmailAlreadyExistException();
            }
        }
        try {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(registeredUser, request.getLocale(), request.getHeader("Origin")));
        } catch (Exception me) {
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        }

        if(registeredUser != null) {
            return this.modelMapper.map(registeredUser, SaveUserDto.class);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Since my angular is served from host:4200 (where host is either localhsot in my dev environment, or 165.22.72.253 in my test environment) and my api is served from host:8761 I have a cors configuration to enable cors request. Here is the configuration :

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://" + clientHost + ":4200");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://" + clientHost + ":80");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Here clientHost is a parameter with either value is localhost when running in dev environment or 165.22.72.253 for my test environment. For most use case this setting is working but it fails in one particular occasion.

The problem arise when a user try to register whith a existing email adress. Then as you can see from the controller method I throw an EmailAlreadyExistException. In dev env everything is working great that is the request return an error code 500 with a message "Email already exist". But in the test environment I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://165.22.72.253:8762/register' from origin 'http://165.22.72.253:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

If useful  here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  tomcat-file:
    container_name: tomcat-file-server
    image: tomcat-file-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tomcat-file.prod.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/vetter_leo/medias:/usr/local/tomcat/src
    ports:
      - "8205:8205"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: helenos-network
```

At this point I don't understand why it's working in dev env and not in test env. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Veteouz what is the origin header which is getting passing is request in test environment?

Comment: can you append. HTTP Request message in raw format which is generated in test environment

Comment: the origin header is "http://165.22.72.253:4200" and the raw request is "POST /register HTTP/1.1
Host: 165.22.72.253:8762
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 107
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://165.22.72.253:4200
Referer: http://165.22.72.253:4200/account/sign-up
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fi;q=0.5"

Comment: http response received for any request received from the same server

Comment: When doing a request with a purpose of authentication, you need to add more headers in the request sent to the server. Back to AngularJS, I remember we were suppose to use `withCredentials=true` when using the HTTP API... Maybe try to find something like that. But you need to add a header in your request: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or something like that

Comment: from my understanding , browser itself blocking request.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is added to my response header for all situation due to my cors settings but not for this particular case when i raise a exception

Comment: Which Docker networking driver are you using?
Can you provide the command used to run yours containers?

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin:<Whatever value your server looks for> should be part of the request header(not response?). I faced a similar issue when making a service broker in spring. In my case the one talking to my broker was the platform and the platform was sending erroneous values in the request.

Comment: did you try proxy like `ingress` in cloud or `ngnix proxy`, this problem appears when the problem of cross-origin. So please conside this as option

Comment: @Vetouz can you add cors response headers received form server.
there will be http response headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: @SamThomas Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be part of the response header. check https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#En-t%C3%AAtes_de_r%C3%A9ponse.

Comment: @DupinderSingh I don't want to use proxy. This issue should be handled by the server

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram Actually the browser does not show me the returned response so I can not show you the response header

Comment: @Alcastic I don't know which network driver I'm using. I edited my post with the docker-compose file. Here is the command I use to run my container : `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: @Alcastic try using firefox and inspect in network tab

Comment: @Vetouz ahh, thanks - I was mistaken, the header name I worked with was a different one, but very similar in name. Thank you for the Info

Comment: @Vetouz I used postman when I was building my broker to iron out kinks like this. It will be perfect for debugging your stuff, if you’re having trouble with getting info from your browser

Answer (score 3):

What I finaly ended up to do was adding an handler to the exception in the controller that return me the right message : this way :

```
@ExceptionHandler({ EmailAlreadyExistException.class })
public String handleException() {
    return "{\"error\": \"" + messages.getMessage("emailAlreadyExist", null, Locale.ENGLISH) + "\"}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to proxy the API calls? In the angular project, you can create a `proxy.conf.json` file and add below configurations.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then in the `package.json` change the start,

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

If you want to do it from the psring side add `@CrossOrigin` to controller.

But if you think you are going to face the same issue in production, my advice is to use a reverse proxy like Nginx. You're Angular application and APIs are served via the same port but all the APIs are prefixed with **api**. From the Nginx side, you can filter API calls using **api** prefix and proxy them to backend service.

Comment: I don't want to use proxy. This issue should be handled by the server

Comment: then you can use "@CrossOrigin" annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot uses a default error controller. You can supply your own and add an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to the response:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RestController
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleErrors(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        String errorMessage = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE).toString();

        return errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it errors out in test environment which is being hosted on DigitalOcean, have you explored if they have a way of overwriting the CORS policy, by their default?
https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/configure-cors/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem that the exception is thrown before the cors filter is called?

Can you try this?

```
  //...

  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
  FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
  bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

  return bean;
}
```